# WooCommerce calculate shipping cost based on price for specific brand

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running an online store selling our own products, and products from different retailers (dropshipping). As each retailer has different shipping costs we have many shipping classes within our shipping method. We want to add products from a new retailer, but they calculate shipping based on total price. I can't figure out a way to have calculated shipping based on price, just for that specific brand. Hopefully somebody can help with some custom code or a plugin that will be able to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Comment: Hey! If a paid plugin is an option, I've used the following plugin for that: https://octolize.com/product/flexible-shipping-pro-woocommerce/

Comment: Hi @thomasberends, thanks a lot for your comment. I've tried the demo and this is indeed what I need. Gonna buy it as well.